# Authentication Scope at firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I recently submittet a "firebase deploy" command, and was notified that my deploy attempt had failed, due to insufficient authentication scope. What does "insufficient authentication scopes", mean?

Comment: I got this too! I see you asked your question 50min ago (at the time of writing). Perhaps it's an active system failure on Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I contacted the support who told me they are working on it.

They also provided a workaround that worked for me. Instead of calling `firebase deploy` to update everything, split the process and call:

`firebase deploy --only hosting 
firebase deploy --only database`

For hosting, an other workaround is to deploy twice (the update actually works, only the 'Current' version is not updated to the latest), and then rollback the latest deploy, which will make the previous (identical) one current.